# VueJs inside WordPress not functioning

Tags: wordpress, vue.js, vuejs2

Currently using WordPress for a simple website and I want to add VueJS into the template.

I am trying to show an `iframe` conditionaly if the Twitch API returns that the specific stream is online.

I included the cdn's in the header.php on top:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.18/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.js"></script>
```

Somewhere at the end of the header.php I create my div that I want to use VueJS with.

```
  <div id="stream">
            {{live}}
            <div v-if="live">
                <iframe src="https://player.twitch.tv/?channel=someTwitchUser" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" scrolling="no" height="678" width="1200"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And at the end finally our VueJS decleration + axios method.

```
<script>
    import axios from 'axios';
    var id = "Client-Id";
    var stream = new Vue({
        el: '#stream',
        data: {
            live: null
        },
        mounted() {
            axios
                .get('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/sometwitchuser', {headers: {id: "somekeyhere"}})
                .then(response => {
                    this.live = response.data.stream;
                    console.log(response.data);
                })
        }
    });
    </script>
```

So basically I can't see anything in the console as I was actually expecting. 
And also, the {{live}} is returned as {{live}} in the view. Which gives me the expression that VueJS isn't doing anything at all.

Am I missing something? Is it not possible to use VueJS like this?
Someone here with experience using vueJs in WordPress?

Comment: ``import Vue from 'vue'``  perhaps? No errors in console? Is vue properly downloaded from CDN (network tab)? Have you tried using Vue debugger tool for chrome?

Comment: Nope no difference and nothing in the console

Comment: Is the script getting executed?

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings it is not being executed no

Answer (score 0):

you cant use the syntax `import * from '...'` in the browser, to use that you have use a module bundler like webpack or parcel,

---

however you already have axios in your scope so i think if you remove
`import axios from 'axios';`
you sould go smooth

Comment: You're right that I shouldn't import it like that and that it shouldn't be required as we already get the Axios in this page. Unfortunately it didn't solve the problem.  
However, I changed the method to a jQuery method and now the axios does run.. but like often a new problem occured: CORS sigh :)